# Flutter Sql FutureBuilder snapshot null

Tags: flutter, future

again. Futures seem to be a constant source of confusion for me.

I am trying to use a FutureBuilder on a page, but the snapshot.data is always null, even though I can print the data from the DBprovider right before it returns.

I have Class 'CentreDetailScreen' which uses initState to create a future.

```
class _CentreDetailScreenState extends State<CentreDetailScreen> {
  Future centreFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    centreFuture = widget._centresBloc.getCentre(widget.centreReference);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: centreFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.none:
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              case ConnectionState.active:
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              case ConnectionState.done:
                print('snapshot: ${snapshot.data}'); <-always null
                return Container(...//build UI
```

In CentresBloc I have:

```
  Future<ClimbingCentre> getCentre(String centreId) async {
    print('BloC get Centre');  <-- this prints
    var _centre = await ClimbDB.db.getCentre(centreId);
    print('Bloc has got a centre $_centre') <-- this doesn't
    return _centre;
  }
```

and then the DBprovider ClimbDB has:

```
Future<ClimbingCentre> getCentre(String centreId) async {
    try {
      var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
      map['action'] = _GET_ONE_ACTION;
      map['centreId'] = centreId;
      final response = await http.post(
          'http://xxx.xxx.xx.x/flutter/climbinside/centre.php',
          body: map);
      if (200 == response.statusCode) {
        var centre = json.decode(response.body);
        var toReturn =
            centre.map((centre) => new ClimbingCentre.fromJson(centre));
         print($toReturn); <-prints 'instance of ClimbingCentre'
        return toReturn;
      } else {
        throw Exception('we were not able to download json data');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Get centre: unable to download JSON');
    }
  }
```

I've tried lot's of different things... sometimes I get errors about Future is not subtype of Future... others cause the 'Unable Download JSON' exception to fire... I can't figure it out all.

I would be most grateful for any help.

Comment: Chech if your `snapshot.error` has something in there. The Future might be done, with an error and not a result.

Comment: tried to `print('snapshot error: ${snapshot.error}');` ?

Comment: @mFeinstein  snapshot.error gives => snap shot is Exception: Get centre: unable to download JSON... which I don't get because the if(200) bit is printing out the response.body just fine.

Comment: You might be returning an incompatible type, so the exception is after your print, as you are using var, to be sure, print the exception `e` or debug the variables.

Comment: Thanks @mFeinstein. The exception e is :  'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<ClimbingCentre>'...

Comment: Check the answer I posted, vote and accept if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should alway check if `snapshot` doesn't have an `error`.

In your case you are getting an error because you defined your variables using `var`, this is tricky and error prone, because you don't get the full help of the compiler to let you know your code will break at runtime. Always try to use a fully typed variable to avoid this gotchas, so avoid `dynamic` as well.

You have to return a variable of the same type `T` of your `Future<T>` in your repository class.

Also, try not to discard the Exception variable, pass it to your new Exception object somehow (apped it to the `String` or ideally, pass it to a constructor as an inner Exception), it contains useful information to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

It worked after rewriting the fromJson method in the model class for ClimbingCentre. I had originally followed the structure from [flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json), like this:

```
  ClimbingCentre.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
      centreId: json['CentreId'],
      name: json['Name'],
      imagePath: json['ImagePath'],
  }
```

But I changed it to this, which I had used in another class:

```
  factory ClimbingCentre.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) {
    ClimbingCentre c = ClimbingCentre(
      centreId: jsonData['CentreId'],
      name: jsonData['Name'],
      imagePath: jsonData['ImagePath'],
    );
    return c;
  }
```